# Parsing a JSON array of JSON objects?

Tags: arrays, json, go

I am trying to get each JSON object out of a JSON array. I get this data via a HTTP post.

I know what my data will look like:

```
   {
    "array":[
       {
          "entity_title":"University of Phoenix", 
          "entity_org_name":"CS Club",
          "possible_user_name":"Johnny Ive",
          "posibble_user_email":"Johhny.Ive@uop.edu",
          "user_position_title":"President",
          "msg_body_id":4
       },
      {
          "entity_title":"University of San Francisco", 
          "entity_org_name":"Marketing club",
          "possible_user_name":"steve jobs",
          "posibble_user_email":"steven.job@uop.edu",
          "user_position_title":"Student",
          "msg_body_id":5
      }
    ]
  }
```

My example code and my structs look like this:

```
    type MsgCreateUserArray struct {
         CreateUser []MsgCreateUserJson `json:"createUserArray"`
    }
    type MsgCreateUserJson struct {
        EntityTitleName string  `json:"entity_title_name"`
        EntityOrgName   string  `json:"entity_org_name"`
        PossibleUserName string `json:"possible_user_name"`
        PossibleUserEmail   string  `json:"possible_user_email"`
        UserPositionTitle   string  `json:"user_position_title"`
        MsgBodyId       string  `json:"msg_body_id, omitempty"` 
    }


func parseJson(rw http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    decodeJson := json.NewDecoder(request.Body)

    var msg MsgCreateUserArray
    err := decodeJson.Decode(&msg)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    log.Println(msg.CreateUser)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", parseJson)
    http.ListenAndServe(":1337", nil)
}
```

I am not sure where how to iterate over the JSON array and get the JSON objects and then just work with the JSON objects.

Comment: Do you get any error?  Can you post it ?

Comment: no, I get the response it looks like this: `2015/03/29 01:01:14 [{University of Phoenix CS Club Johnny Ive Johhny.Ive@uop.edu President } {University of San Francisco Marketing club steve jobs steven.job@uop.edu Student }]`

Comment: Field names don't match (e.g. you have `json:"entity_title_name"` but your json has "entitiy_title", and `createUserArray` vs `array`); some fields have the wrong type (e.g. your `MsgBodyId string` but the JSON has a number; struct tags shouldn't contain spaces (e.g. remove the space from `json:"msg_body_id, omitempty"`) … etc …

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this as your structs,

```
type MsgCreateUserArray struct {
    CreateUser []MsgCreateUserJson `json:"array"`
}

type MsgCreateUserJson struct {
    EntityOrgName     string  `json:"entity_org_name"`
    EntityTitle       string  `json:"entity_title"`
    MsgBodyID         int64   `json:"msg_body_id,omitempty"`
    PosibbleUserEmail string  `json:"posibble_user_email"`
    PossibleUserName  string  `json:"possible_user_name"`
    UserPositionTitle string  `json:"user_position_title"`
}
```

Your `entity_title_name` is not named correctly, nor is the top level `array`.  After you decode into a `MsgCreateUserArray` you can iterate over the `CreateUser` slice to get each `MsgCreateUserJson`