# Parsing an array/slice sent by server

Tags: arrays, json, go

A server is sending back such a response:

```
me@linux:~> curl -X GET http://*.*.*.*:8080/profiles

[
        {
                "ProfileID": 1,
                "Title": "65micron"
        },
        {
                "ProfileID": 2,
                "Title": "80micron"
        }
]
```

I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29326193/3405291) to parse the response as JSON but it **only** works if the server response is like this:

```
{
    "array": [
        {
                "ProfileID": 1,
                "Title": "65micron"
        },
        {
                "ProfileID": 2,
                "Title": "80micron"
        }
    ]
}
```

Does anybody know how I can parse the server response as JSON?

---

One idea which occurred to me is to add `{ "array":` to the beginning of `http.Response.Body` buffer and also add `}` to the its end, then use [the standard solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29326193/3405291). However, I'm not sure if that's the best idea.

Comment: Your json isn't valid, you are adding an extra ',' at the end of your objects. You can validate it using https://jsonlint.com/. Correct it and try again

Comment: @AhmedEssam Thanks, my JSONs are super lengthy. I just pasted two key/values here as samples and I forgot to remove the extra `,` I'm going to fix my question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unmarshal directly into an array

```
data := `[
    {
        "ProfileID": 1,
        "Title": "65micron"
    },
    {
        "ProfileID": 2,
        "Title": "80micron"
    }]`

type Profile struct {
    ProfileID int
    Title     string
}

var profiles []Profile

json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &profiles)
```

You can also read directly from the `Request.Body`.

```
func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    var profiles []Profile
    json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&profiles)
    // use `profiles`
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/tFZZbPW30Oz)

Answer (score 1):

You should define a struct

```
type Profile struct {
    ID int `json:"ProfileID"`
    Title string `json:"Title"`
}
```

After that decode response

```
var r []Profile
err := json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&r)
```